# Adding a spinner in alertdialog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-alertdialog, android-spinner

I'm working on a little project and I was wondering if this type was of spinner is a default in android, since they use this picture in their android development guides? If not, how would one go about making one like this?

[image: Spinner inside an AlertDialog?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view you are looking at is NOT a spinner, it's a NumberPicker. Take a look at the official Android Docs here; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html